# Very slow page copy in back end

Tags: performance, typo3-8.x

I have a large TYPO3 8.7.39 installation with about 2500 pages and 30 different languages.

When I try to copy a page (which is intended as a landing page template) in the back end it takes about 5 minutes to finish the operation on my local machine. The page contains 130 content elements (including self written extensions and ext gridelements) which reference several images.

When I log all database queries performed during copy operation I get about 8000 queries. As 8000 db operations per 5 minutes comes down to about 1 db operation per 0.04 sec the time it takes to copy the page seems reasonable.

My question: Is there any option to speed up page copy? Maybe copying pages is at least possible via cli or scheduler task, which would be a work around.

System Info:

- TYPO3 8.7.39
- Running Ubuntu 18.04
- Database structure is up to date
- #pages ~ 2500, #num_languages = 30, #num_fe_users ~ 80

Answer (score 0):

I could work around the problem by creating a command controller that uses the datahandler to copy a source page to a target page.

```
/**
 * @param int $src
 * @param int $target
 */
public function copyCommand(int $src, int $target): void
{
    /** @var PageRepository $pageRepository */
    $pageRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(PageRepository::class);
    $srcPage = $pageRepository->getPage($src);

    if (empty($srcPage)) {
        throw new InvalidArgument("$src ist not a valid page uid");
    }

    if (empty($pageRepository->getPage($target))) {
        throw new InvalidArgument("$target ist not a valid page uid");
    }


    $cmd = [
        'pages' => [
            $src => [
                'copy' => [
                    'action' => 'paste',
                    'target' => $target,
                    'update' => [
                        'title' => sprintf("Copy of #%d: %s", $src, $srcPage['title']),
                        'hidden' => 1,
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    /** @var DataHandler $dataHandler */
    $dataHandler = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DataHandler::class);

    $dataHandler->start([], $cmd);
    $dataHandler->process_cmdmap();

}
```